# How do you store an erb value inside input tags in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb

When I try to show the name of a person inside my input tag using value, the name gets cut off as soon as there is a space. So when it should say John Doe, the input is only showing John. Does anyone know why it would do this in my rails app? The database is correct, and everything shows properly if I use  tags.

```
form class="panel data-abide" action="" id="form1">
  <fieldset >
    <legend>Please Enter the Information Below</legend>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>Adjuster's Name
        <input class="adjustorInfo" value=<%= @adjuster.adjuster_name %>/>
     </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the value for the `value` tag has not been put in quotes.
You should change it to

```
<input class="adjustorInfo" value="<%= @adjuster.adjuster_name %>"/>
```

---

When you pass it without quotes, the corresponding HTML looks like this

```
<input class="adjustorInfo" value=John Doe/>
```

which is then converted to what you are seeing

```
<input class="adjustorInfo" value="John"/>
```

Passing it inside quotes forms this which is the expected value

```
<input class="adjustorInfo" value="John Doe"/>
```